# move/copy a file to iCloud

Tags: objective-c, icloud

I am a beginner using Objective-C. I used the following code to move a file to iCloud but it gives an error that `The operation could not be completed. The file exists.`

```
//store the file locally in document folder 
NSArray *docPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *filePath  = [docPaths objectAtIndex:0];
filePath = [filePath stringByAppendingString:@"/"];
filePath = [filePath stringByAppendingString:fileName];

NSString *writeError = nil;
NSData * fileData = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList:dataDic format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 errorDescription:&writeError];

if ([fileData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES]) {
    NSLog(@"Server file is stored locally");
}else {
    NSLog(@"%@", writeError);
}


 // store the file in iCloud folder

NSURL *ubiquitousURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];
NSString *tmpubiquitousURL = ubiquitousURL.absoluteString;
tmpubiquitousURL = [tmpubiquitousURL stringByAppendingString:fileName];
NSURL *ubi2 = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:tmpubiquitousURL];

[[NSFileManager defaultManager] setUbiquitous:YES itemAtURL:filePathURL destinationURL:ubi2 error:&error];
```

I used the following to remove the file from iCloud but it gives an error that `Cannot disable syncing on an un-synced file.`

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] setUbiquitous:NO itemAtURL:filePathURL destinationURL:ubi2 error:&error];
```

I checked the availability of iCloud in my app delegate and it's available. The file is an XML file (.plist) and I have a local copy stored in `NSDocumentDirectory`.

Overall, I want to sync that file in iCloud so it will be accessible on all devices using my app. I have been struggling with this for 2 days, so if you could help me to resolve the problem I would appreciate it.

Note: I would rather not to use UIDocument, however, if that is the only option please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same problem while using the code

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] setUbiquitous:NO itemAtURL:filePathURL destinationURL:ubi2 error:&error];
```

you have to change the code like below for this to work correctly

```
  [[[NSFileManager alloc]init]setUbiquitous:YES itemAtURL:filePathURL destinationURL:ubi2 error:nil];
```

this code is for moving a file to icloud, also you should change the name of the file you are moving. It should not be same.